# Does Hybris support Proposals out of the box (OOTB)?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Proposals is a functionality where a user can convert the existing cart into a proposal. Anyone know if Hybris provides that OOTB?

Comment: Do you mean [Commerce Quotes](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/a795b4722f6942c091ef716c66ddb37d.html)?

Comment: No, not quotes.

Comment: You have accepted the answer below which point to the Quotes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a B2C accelerator check [Commerce Quotes](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/a795b4722f6942c091ef716c66ddb37d.html).

> Commerce Quotes enables buyers to create quotes and negotiate the final price of an order using the storefront.

If you are using a B2B accelerator check [Customer/Merchant Approval](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8ac2500f8669101493e69e1392b970fd.html#loio8ac2500f8669101493e69e1392b970fd__b2bcheckoutandorderprocess-orderapproval).

> Depending on the configuration of the B2B store, orders may require approval from the customer's organization, from the merchant, or both.

Comment: This helped, thanks.  But for the the B2B accelerator, there is a process when the user submits an order, and if it passes the threshold, the order will be submitted in an 'Requires Approval' status.  There are several users OOTB which I have tried but non of those lead to that status.  Do you know if there is a user needs to be enabled for that or a functionality to be configured? (I know this used to work before OOTB without any problems)

Comment: Ok, I figured.  Initially the order says created, and then behind the scene a job gets run and the status changes to Pending Approval.  This process is not like what it used to be before.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if you mean this, but Hybris provides a 'wishlist' functionality. Just search in the wiki 'wishlist extension' or 'wishlist2service api'.

The wishlist is quite the same as a cart in Hybris. It just provides some more features than a cart. If you have access to the wiki here are the links

- https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/wishlist+Extension+-+Technical+Guide
- https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c86a01786691014b68dae2f881531cd.html
- https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c7c9669866910148d5fd951061d28b2.html

Comment: wishlist is a good example.  But with proposals functionality, will need to get it approved by the seller. Thanks!